# How to prove that F is continuous?

Tags: integration, continuity, partial-derivative

I have the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous and i know that it I can differentiate it to the first variable and that $D_1f : \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. How do i prove continuity for the following function? $$ F(x) = \int_a^xf(x,y)dy, x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. By the continuity property of $f$, it follows there exists $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{align}
|f(x+h, y)-f(x, y)|<\epsilon \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ |f(x+h, y)| <\epsilon+|f(x, y)|
\end{align}
whenever $|h|<\delta$. Also, by the mean value theorem, we know there exists $ \xi \in (x, x+h)$ such that
\begin{align}
f(x+h, y)-f(x, y) = D_1f(\xi, y)h.
\end{align}
Combining the above two facts yield the estimate
\begin{align}
|F(x+h) - F(x)| =&\  \left| \int^{x+h}_a f(x+h, y)\ dy - \int^x_a f(x, y)\ dy \right|\\
\leq&\ \int^{x+h}_x|f(x+h, y)|\ dy+ \int^x_a|f(x+h, y)-f(x, y)|\ dy\\
\leq&\ \int^{x+h}_x [|f(x, y)|+\epsilon]\ dy +\int^x_a |D_1 f(\xi, y)||h|\ dy \\
\leq&\ [|f(x, y)|+\epsilon]||h| + \sup_{\xi\in [x, x+h]}|D_1f(\xi, y)||h||x-a|.
\end{align}
Hence the problem can be finished using the usual $\epsilon-\delta$ argument which I will leave as an exercise for the reader.